# Android in app purchase issue: You already own this item

Tags: google-play-store, in-app-purchase

I am interested in purchasing the Game from Google Play Store, but when I try to purchase it using the **buy** Button in game menu it takes me to Play store and there I get a message `"You already own this item"`, but when I click on details button in the message box the play store application crashes.

Now I don't know even if I own this or not. If I own it then why didn't I received this full version and if I do not own it then how I will be able to purchase it?

Comment: Which app has this problem? Some apps do their own transaction restoring on the first start (and don't support rebuying. I had that with an earlier version of pinball arcade some time ago). File a bug report for the app or clear the app data and restart with a working internet connection (leave droidwall if you use it disabled).

Comment: Sometimes this happens when there is an error while completing the transaction. Can you do the following: **Settings->Apps->All->Google Play Store** press **Clear data** and **Clear cache**, then check if the issue is resolved?

Comment: Thanks for your reponses
The Game is "Rise of Glory", I tried to clear the cache and clear the Applications data (Play Sore and the Game) but the issue is not resolved. I am still receiving the same dialog i.e. "You already own this item", clicking on the detail crashes the play store application after a message "Play Store Stopped Unexpectedly ".

Comment: Ok, This is a known issue and you can find the issue at


http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs&ki_topic=1319135

[#702829] Falsely receiving error: "You already own this item"

Google Technical team is working on this and hopefully this issue will be resolved.

Comment: Hmm the link to the issues doesn't work. If you got a working link, feel free to post it as answer to your own question.

Comment: When you go the the webpage of play.google.com => apps => may apps, does it appear there?

Comment: Did u try purchasing from web `https://play.google.com/store`

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Summed up from the comments:</sup>

This was a known issue with *Google Play*, which meanwhile is resolved (read more on [this Google support page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/known-issues/1319135?hl=en), opening the "fixed/resolved" item, and there you see `[#8849329] Falsely received error: "You already own this item"`, together with more details).

Answer (score 0):

The best option that worked for me was to install the following app that will allow you to download the app again "Purchased Apps (Reinstall your paid apps)" https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.azefsw.purchasedapps&hl=en

Comment: This did not work for me. Continues to say ERROR you already own this item I own it but can't download it. Thing is I did a factory data reset and list it that way.